# What's upcoming in Bot Framework V5?

Tags: botframework

just noticed in https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues that devs are mentioning **V5** of the SDK. Can anyone from the team share any high-level plans for the framework. Just curious as it's a core part of my application. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The team is not here, you need to ask this to them directly.